# how can insert multiple dates from sql file in a phonegap sqlite

Tags: jquery, ajax, sqlite, cordova

Im trying to save the instruction from sql file to create a local sqlite database in phonegap. If you supose that you create well the database, I have this function

```
function populateDB(tx) {
                     var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();                  
                     xhReq.open("GET", "prueba.sql", false);
                     xhReq.send(null);
                     var r= xhReq.responseText;
                     var sentencias = r.split(";"); 


                     alert("SENT="+sentencias);
                     var aux="";                    

                    for (var i = 0; i < sentencias.length; i++) {
                        aux='"'+sentencias[i]+'"';

                       tx.executeSql(aux);
                    }
            }
```

But this dont insert nothing, you can see in the browser the sentences, but dont do nothing in the database, the database is empty...
But if you write:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Linea VALUES(1,'Abretia 18','Atomoxetina','18 mg',NULL,NULL,'Oral','Cápsulas','7','Medicamento Controlado','cilindrico','blanco y bordeaux','N/A','N/A','N/A','N/A')");
```

This is well!!

Why? How can fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, quotes `"` are used to differentiate strings from variable names, but are not actually part of the string.

When your string already is in a variable, you must not insert an extra pair of quotes, because those would end up in the database.

Just execute the strings directly:

```
aux=sentencias[i];
tx.executeSql(aux);
```

Comment: I insert extra quotes because I dont have any in the variable only a simple quotes for the values, the problem is that the tx.executeSql is not working when there are a lot of instruction together...if you do the instruction one to one is working fine!!